# sent data to paticular socket from server when have multiple client

Tags: c

I have 4 different application running.so every application can send data to server. now i want to send data to paticular socket (server and client are done through socket programming)
from server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a socket, first you establish a connection between a server and a client (using `connect` system call on the client side, and `bind`, `listen`, and `accept` system calls on the server side). You can have many such connections, from a server to different clients. The server can send data on any of these established connections.

The [Sockets Tutorial](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) can assist you in this case.

---

If you want multiple reads/writes by the server to happen *at the same time*, you have to use [non-blocking](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html) sockets or multiple threads.

Comment: serve can send acknowledgement to client from which it is receving data.now suppose client A is sending data and i want that server want to send data to client B then how i will send data??

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're using TCP/IP, or UDP).

A socket endpoint is the IP address and port number combined.  So, on your host you would have your various servers listen on different port numbers.  For example a web server may listen on port 80, ssh on a different port etc.